# Deploying every GitHub PR to separate Azure instances

Tags: azure, github, deployment, azure-devops, devops

I have a project with different branches and every time when a PR is created from one of those branches to main I want that PR to be deployed on Azure.

I found something like this but it is only for Static Apps but my project is dynamic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/review-publish-pull-requests

Comment: github doesnt really care if its static or dynamic, just create the builds and force builds on PR

Comment: @4c74356b41 Github does not care but azure does. I can make a build pipeline which builds every PR but I am having problems with release pipeline. I cant figure out how to make different App Services or something like that dynamically. I need it because the amount of PRs is dynamic and I want a new instance to be created for each new PR.

Comment: so whats the issue? create an app service inside each PR and use that to deploy your code?

Comment: @4c74356b41 The issue is that I need to create a new App Service programmatically. I dont want to manually create App Service for each PR.

Comment: so whats the issue? there are numerous ways to do that

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can you show me one if them because I have been researching this for a few days now and I did not see anything relevant.

Comment: like really? few days? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/samples-cli

Answer (score 0):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/static-web-app-pr-workflow-for-azure-app-service-using-azure-devops/

This has

- PullRequest triggers a pipeline
- If pipeline was triggered by a PullRequest, a staging slot is created and the app is deployed.
- Add comment to PullRequest with the environment URL.

Some key things to note:

```
// Slot name
   az webapp deployment slot create \
       --name $(webApp.name) \
       --resource-group $(webApp.resourceGroup) \
       --slot staging-pr-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
```

```
// Conditionals
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```

You might need to adapt it a bit since your PR is in GitHub, but the principle stays the same. Check if `System.PullRequest.PullRequestId` is also populated, it could be according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pre-defined-variables). You can also use a dedicated AppService instead of a slot if you prefer, though I would stick with the slot.